# Responsive row of icons

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CCS and I'm trying to create a little personal website. I made up a design in Sketch and I've managed to successfully reproduce it on HTML and CSS. I have three big icons at the bottom that send you to different pages (Twitter, Instagram and Tumblr). On a big screen, the website looks great. However, when loading it on a small screen, it looks bad. I want the three icons to stack each one on top of another. Here's a picture of what it looks like now: [image]

What I would like is that each icon is on top of the other, so it would be Twitter, below Instagram, and under that, Tumblr. I've tried many things, like setting up columns and I've looked many tutorials on the internet, but I haven't really found a solution.

Thanks!

EDIT: Code portions
HTML

```
<div class="social-container">
<div class="twitter">
  <a href="http://twitter.com/jmml97" target="_blank"><img src="images/Twitter Logo.png" alt="Twitter"/></a>
</div>
<div class="instagram">
  <a href="http://instagram.com/jmml97" target="_blank"><img src="images/Instagram Logo.png" alt="Instagram"/></a>
</div>
<div class="tumblr">
  <a href="http://jmml97.tumblr.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/Tumblr Logo.png" alt="Tumblr"/></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.social-container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: block;


  width: 60%; 
  margin: 8px auto; padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;

  -webkit-columns: 3 33%;
  -moz-columns: 3 33%;
  columns: 3 33%;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

  .social-container {
    -moz-columns:    1 100%;
    -webkit-columns: 1 100%;
    columns:         1 100%;
    display: inline;
    margin: 8px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that using `media` queries. Just define a style for smaller screens. Usually, the size for phone-sized screens is considered to be 768px.

For example, if you are using `img` for your icons, then you could simply change the `display` for smaller screens:

***Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/rvjmk90e/***

***Demo Snippet***:

```css
div.jumbo {
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 60%; 
    margin: 8px auto; padding: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) { 
    img {
        display: block;
        margin: 8px auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbo">
    <h2>Hola</h2>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120/&text=tw" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120/&text=Ig" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120/&text=tm" />
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work here... The same problem is present. If possible, could you  try the code I provided? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should add the relevant portions of your code in the question itself. Links to offsite resources are not looked upon. More info here: [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and here: [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm adding them now.

Comment: @JoséMaría: There is nothing wrong in your approach. Only problem was incorrect usage of CSS `column`. Just change the number that's it. See: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/7cht6fx9/ Resize the result pane to see the effect.

Comment: Oooh, I see! Thanks! It has helped me figure out the problem. Not only that, but I had different classes for each icon and they had a width, margin and alignment. Deleting that and changing the column number has solved the problem. Thanks very much!

Comment: Umm, another thing. Is is possible to change the distance of each other when they're stacked? They get very close and I would like them a bit separated from each other. Thank you again for your time and help!

Comment: Great, @JoséMaría to have sorted it out. For the spacing, just increase the margin or column-gap.

Comment: Thank you again! Your code examples you added have helped me solve the problem easily. I'll mark now your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

A better way for responsive web is not to use `<img />` but insert images as the background `background-image`.

With `media query` set `width: 100%` and everything will be fine. If they have **100%**, put together under himself.

Comment: But what if  I don't want them to be the background? I add them as the background of a div or what?

Comment: Set blocks around the image desired width and `<img />` give `100%` and `height` set `auto`.

Comment: Also, the images are links to webpages, does it interfere?

Comment: Link doesn't affect anything. Please specify what you need more :)

Comment: *The best way for responsive web is not to use img*: Source? Or is it your/somebody's personal opinion?

Comment: Is only my personal opinion. You can then use the sprite, better define the width / height.

Comment: Then it would be imperative to state that in your answer by saying IMO. Otherwise, it sounds authoritative without any evidence.